# How to import a certificate's public and private keys via ml-gradle?

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

How can I add public and private keys for a certificate to a certificate template via `ml-gradle`?

I'm trying to configure some new servers entirely via ml-gradle + DHF 5. I can set up the certificate templates by adding a configuration file to `ml-config/security/certificate-templates`. I already have an SSL certificate for these servers, but can't figure out how to import them without using the admin web interface.

There is a REST endpoint for performing certificate operations at [/manage/v2/certificate-templates/{id|name}](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v2/certificate-templates/%5Bid-or-name%5D#insertHC), so I guess I just want to invoke that as part of the deployment process in the right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to do that via a custom task today - https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Writing-your-own-task .

If you think of a way for how you'd like to store those files in your project directory such that ml-gradle knows what calls to make for them, definitely open a ticket in ml-gradle with your idea.